# Playing an audio file in Android's music player

Tags: android

I have some audio files in my Android Project's raw folder. I wish to play these audio files through Android's default Music Player. Could someone share some sample code snippet to explain the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

Uri data = Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath()+"/" + fileName);
String type = "audio/mp3";
intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
startActivity(intent);
```

`fileName` is the name of your audio on your `SDCard`.

Comment: What if the files are in Project's raw folder?

Comment: If they are in Raw Folder, specify the path to that file, for example fileName = "/com.package/data/media/audio/song.mp3". Or what ever the path is.

Comment: I tried your way, but the app crashes with "ActivityNotFoundException".. No activity found to handle intent....

Comment: ActivityNotFoundException should not appear using this code, something else or some were else is the problem with ActivityNotFoundException.

Comment: Ok, my project's package name is "com.example.audio" and my audio file  is "sound.mp3" in res->raw folder... So i used the File Path as "/com.example.audio/res/raw/sound.mp3". When running the app... a toast message is raised..."The player doesn't support this type of file"

Comment: @AnujOberoi I Guess you are using HTC, some of the players does not support some audio files, try downloading any Audio Player from the market "MX Player" for example, and choose that one from the list.

Answer (score 1):

First declare `MediaPlayer` object :

```
MediaPlayer mSoundPlayer;
```

Add this function :

```
//Play music
    public void playSound(int id){
            try{
                mSoundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, id);
                mSoundPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                        mSoundPlayer.start();

                    }

                });
                mSoundPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener () {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mSoundPlayer.release();
                    }});
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.v("Sound Exception","Sound Exception = "+e.getMessage());
            }
    }
```

Call with this :

```
playSound(R.raw.sound1);
```

It will be a good practice to release `MediaPlayer` :

```
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if(mSoundPlayer!=null)
            mSoundPlayer.release();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: i want that, on the click of a button, the audio file is launched in the Android's music player application. With this procedure, it runs in the background and I'll have to create the play/pause/stop etc buttons.

Comment: @user1951199 okay I thought you want to play in background. anyways is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code snippet...

[For playing audio files in android](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)

[Playing audio](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-play-video-and-audio-android)

```
public void splashPlayer() {
 VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
 setContentView(videoHolder);
 Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
    + R.raw.splash);
 videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
 videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
   jumpMain(); //jump to the next Activity
  }
 });
 videoHolder.start();
}
```

For complete tutorial go for [this](http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/06/how-to-play-video-from-resources.html)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code:-

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
Uri uri = Uri.parse("R.raw.fashion.mp3");//the audio file
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent); 

}
});
```

But when I run this code; the app crashes and the LogCat shows: "ActivityNotFoundException"...No activity found to handle intent.

Answer (score -1):

Try this might it help.

```
Uri data = Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath()+"/" + audioName);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, data);

        String type = "audio/mp3";
        intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The questions asks to play the audio from res/raw directory and you are answering by using external storage.